Does anyone own the copyright to a “Mandela Effect”?
Many people claim to have seen a 1990s movie called Shazam, in which Sinbad played a genie. However, there is no evidence of the movie ever actually being made, and Sinbad himself has said that it does not exist.
Say I was a filmmaker and I decided to make a movie called Shazam about a genie. I incorporate plot points from “memories” of the movie, and maybe I even got Sinbad onboard.
Could anyone sue me for this? If so, who?
(For purposes of this discussion, disregard the unrelated Marvel Shazam movies.)

it was Kazaam, it starred Shaq. We can't disregard the non-Marvel DC movie, it has the same name as your movie.  Sometihing that doesn't exist won't be copyrighted.

@TigerGuy It's actually really easy to disregard any given fact when running a legal analysis. If you can't do it, though, you can also just disregard the question and leave it for someone who know how to address it.

@bdb484, sure it's easy, but your legal analysis would be wrong.

https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/Mandela-effect

The legal analysis of a hypothetical isn't wrong when it's confined to the actual hypothetical.

@TigerGuy I am well aware of Kazaam starring Shaquille o’Neal. And there is no proof that that has anything to do with this question.

@TigerGuy And besides that, you completely missed the point of the question.

@bdb484 Ok, I'm here to learn, and willing to ask a separate question if needed, (that will certainly get immediately downvoted...) but how can one perform an accurate and correct legal "analysis" while willfully disregarding a key factor?  e.g. "Can I start a hamburger chain called McDonalds with no risk of trademark infringement?"  The answer is clearly NO, but if we disregard the ubiquitous corporate behemoth we all know so well the answer becomes YES.  As I agreed, it's very easy to simply disregard something if asked, but doing so flips the answer.  Am I missing something here?!

@MichaelHall If we were actually this guy's lawyer taking actual money to give him an actual legal opinion for him to actually rely on, then yes, ignoring key facts would be malpractice. But we're only talking about hypotheticals to advance an understanding of how the law works; in that case, counterfactuals are very useful tools for illustrating what switches you can flip to make legal questions turn out one way or another.

See 17 USC § 102:

Copyright protection subsists, in accordance with this title, in original works of authorship fixed in any tangible medium of expression, now known or later developed, from which they can be perceived, reproduced, or otherwise communicated, either directly or with the aid of a machine or device

Copyright does not subsist in the ideas and memories not fixed in any tangible medium of expression.


Say I was a filmmaker and I decided to make a movie called Shazam
about a genie. I incorporate plot points from “memories” of the movie,
and maybe I even got Sinbad onboard.

This is not sufficient to establish copyright derivative work infringement, even if there is a original work and this is what it came from. Copyright protects particular expressions of an idea, and not the idea itself.
A title is generally too trivial to receive copyright protection. Basic concepts and plot points or a choice of actors are insufficient to make it a derivative work. Moreover reiterating genre conventions is not a copyright violation.

Note that while titles can’t be protected by copyright, they can be registered as trademarks and will then be protected.

@MikeScott Only if they are used in commerce, which the scenario in the question specifically rules out.
